# Grafana: Dynamic Playlist

Tags: grafana

I have a set of dashboards which show data from different devices in grafana. Every devices has his own dashboard. Also this dashboards have a singlestat which indicates the status of the device (**online** / **offline**).

What I try to achive now is a playlist which just shows the dashboards where the singlestat is set to "**online**". Also if i started the playlist and a device came "online" I want it to be added automatically to the playlist.

Is there a way I can achive this ? So far I just saw that it is possible to manually add dasboards to a playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do this. The only dynamic playlist feature is one where you create a playlist by using Dashboard tags. Allows you easily add / change playlist by tagging dashboards.